# Finding the smallest and largest date in my dataset in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset with Character and Date variables. I would like to find the smallest and largest date in my dataset.

I am trying to use the pmin function but this does not seem to be working. Once the max and min date have been extracted, I want to create a dataset with a sequence of dates between them. For example, if the oldest date is 2021-02-01 (from new column) and most recent is 2022-06-20 (from old column) I want to create a list of dates between the two.

Table:

| ID | Old | New | Tier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | NA | 2021-02-01 | A |
| 002 | NA | 2021-02-01 | A |
| 003 | NA | 2021-02-21 | A |
| 004 | NA | 2021-04-21 | A |
| 005 | NA | 2021-04-21 | A |
| 006 | NA | 2021-04-21 | A |
| 006 | 2022-06-20 | 2021-04-21 | B |
| 002 | 2021-08-10 | 2021-04-21 | B |
| 003 | 2022-06-20 | 2021-05-01 | B |
| 003 | 2022-06-20 | 2021-05-01 | B |
| 003 | 2021-08-10 | 2021-05-21 | B |
| 003 | 2021-08-10 | 2021-07-21 | B |

Format variables in extended data: using str()

$ Old                         : Date, format: "2021-04-30"
$ Id                    : chr
$ New                          : Date, format: "2021-02-03" "2021-02-03"
$ New1                     : Date, format: NA NA NA NA ...
$ New2                    : Date, format: "2021-01-10" "2021-01-10"
$ New3                     : Date, format: NA NA "2021-06-10" NA ...
$ New4                     : Date, format: NA NA NA NA ...
$ New5                    : Date, format: NA NA "2022-07-10" NA ...

Comment: Does `pmin(min(df$Old, na.rm = TRUE), min(df$New, na.rm = TRUE))` work for you?

Comment: The issue is I do not want to specify just one column in the min and max functions, I want it to parse the entire dataset and find the biggest/smallest date value. For example, lets say I had another column that was df$rejected which also had numerous dates. I would want it to parse that for min and max dates as well. Would this require a for loop?

Comment: No, you can select columns of a particular type. Are your date columns all in actual date format?

Comment: @AllanCameron yes they are! I have edited my comment to show variable class types

Comment: Would love to learn how to parse by column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you can get the date range like this:

```r
range(unlist(df[sapply(df, class) == "Date"]), na.rm = TRUE) |>
  as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01")
#> [1] "2021-02-01" "2022-06-20"
```

**Explanation**

To work with just columns of class "Date" in your data frame, you can do `df[sapply(df, class) == "Date"]`. If you `unlist` these columns, they form a single vector from which you can get the `range` (i.e. min / max), being sure you exclude `NA` values.

Unfortunately, these steps remove the class attribute from the vector, so you need to convert it back to a date.

Answer (score 1):

Same basic idea as Allan but an approach that preserves the class:

```
do.call(range, Filter(\(x) inherits(x, "Date"), dat))

[1] "2022-06-22" "2022-08-07"
```

Data:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = Sys.Date() + sample(50, 5),
                  b = letters[1:5],
                  c = Sys.Date() + sample(50, 5),
                  d = runif(5))
```